# Unable to deploy DevStack on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: openstack, devstack

I'm trying to deploy OpenStack using DevStack on Ubuntu 22.04, I'am facing issues on running stack.sh.
I'm not sure if it's related to the git repo code or related to the system configuration or som missing packages, please advise.

Here below the error log:

```
fatal: your current branch 'master' does not have any commits yet
+functions-common:git_clone:680            cd /opt/stack/devstack
+lib/neutron-legacy:install_mutnauq:469    setup_develop /opt/stack/neutron
+inc/python:setup_develop:334              local bindep
+inc/python:setup_develop:335              [[ /opt/stack/neutron == -bindep* ]]
+inc/python:setup_develop:339              local project_dir=/opt/stack/neutron
+inc/python:setup_develop:340              local extras=
+inc/python:setup_develop:341              _setup_package_with_constraints_edit /opt/stack/neutron -e
+inc/python:_setup_package_with_constraints_edit:360  local bindep
+inc/python:_setup_package_with_constraints_edit:361  [[ /opt/stack/neutron == -bindep* ]]
+inc/python:_setup_package_with_constraints_edit:365  local project_dir=/opt/stack/neutron
+inc/python:_setup_package_with_constraints_edit:366  local flags=-e
+inc/python:_setup_package_with_constraints_edit:367  local extras=
++inc/python:_setup_package_with_constraints_edit:374  cd /opt/stack/neutron
++inc/python:_setup_package_with_constraints_edit:374  pwd
+inc/python:_setup_package_with_constraints_edit:374  project_dir=/opt/stack/neutron
+inc/python:_setup_package_with_constraints_edit:376  '[' -n /opt/stack/requirements ']'
+inc/python:_setup_package_with_constraints_edit:380  local name
++inc/python:_setup_package_with_constraints_edit:381  awk '/^name.*=/ {print $3}' /opt/stack/neutron/setup.cfg
awk: fatal: cannot open file `/opt/stack/neutron/setup.cfg' for reading: No such file or directory
+inc/python:_setup_package_with_constraints_edit:381  name=
+inc/python:_setup_package_with_constraints_edit:1  exit_trap
+./stack.sh:exit_trap:516                  local r=2
++./stack.sh:exit_trap:517                  jobs -p
+./stack.sh:exit_trap:517                  jobs=
+./stack.sh:exit_trap:520                  [[ -n '' ]]
+./stack.sh:exit_trap:526                  '[' -f '' ']'
+./stack.sh:exit_trap:531                  kill_spinner
+./stack.sh:kill_spinner:426               '[' '!' -z '' ']'
+./stack.sh:exit_trap:533                  [[ 2 -ne 0 ]]
+./stack.sh:exit_trap:534                  echo 'Error on exit'
Error on exit
+./stack.sh:exit_trap:536                  type -p generate-subunit
+./stack.sh:exit_trap:537                  generate-subunit 1656624514 146 fail
+./stack.sh:exit_trap:539                  [[ -z /opt/stack/logs ]]
+./stack.sh:exit_trap:542                  /usr/bin/python3.10 /opt/stack/devstack/tools/worlddump.py -d /opt/stack/logs
/opt/stack/devstack/tools/worlddump.py:22: DeprecationWarning: The distutils package is deprecated and slated for removal in Python 3.12. Use setuptools or check PEP 632 for potential alternatives
  from distutils import spawn
```

Any clue ?

Answer (score 0):

it says:

> cannot open file `/opt/stack/neutron/setup.cfg' for reading: No such
> file or directory

check if the file exist `sudo cd /opt/stack/neutron/setup.cfg`
otherwise create it ([this is the code](https://github.com/openstack/neutron/blob/master/setup.cfg)) manually and re-run the installation